# Проблемы использования cin с double и char одновременно

Tags: c++, input, cin

```
    double amount = 0;
    char currency;
    cin >> amount >> currency;
    if (currency == 'e')
    //..Do stuff..//
```

Имеется следующий фрагмент кода. При вводе с клавиатуры значения, вроде 123e, программа начинает работать неправильно.
Мне удалось выяснить, что cin при этом переходит в состояние failed, сам же amount не изменяется.
Полагаю, это связано с тем, что 123e интерпретируется как что-то в экспоненциальной записи.

P.S. при вводе 123 e (с пробелом), всё работает как надо.
Есть ли способ заставить программу корректно слопать 123е?
Так же, хотелось бы понять, почему cin вообще воспринимает e как экспоненту?

Comment: ну так, есть экспотенциальная форма - 123e3 == 123000. Скорее всего лучше прочитать все как строку, а потом распарсить отдельно.

Comment: А заставить игнорировать её нельзя? Кроме того, числа-то после экпоненты нет. С++ вообще это как NaN воспринимает, видимо.

Comment: может Вам нужно читать просто int,  а потом char? Ну или просто добавьте пробел между числом и буквой